# JFreeChart connect one point to all other around

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

is it possible to connect one point to all others around  in JFreeChart 

here how it should looks
[image]

so all the points around connected to X point

```js
chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        Shape cross = ShapeUtilities.createDiagonalCross(3, 1);
        Shape somehing = ShapeUtilities.createDiamond(4);



        final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, false);
        renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(1, false);
        renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(2, false);
        renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(3, false);

        renderer.setSeriesShape(0, cross);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(1, somehing);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(2, somehing);
        renderer.setSeriesShape(3, somehing);

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.BLUE);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.YELLOW);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, Color.green);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);


        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.BLACK);
        // change the auto tick unit selection to integer units only...
        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        // OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION COMPLETED.

        return chart;
```

thank You

Comment: What do you call this kind of plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a custom renderer. This minimal example overrides the [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) method `drawPrimaryLine()`. It draws the lines relative to the item having `anchor` as its series index. You'll need to recapitulate the existing implementation, replacing the lines shown below.

Addendum: The example simply passes `anchor` as a constructor parameter, but you can extend `XYDataset` to include a unique value for each series.

[image]

```
MyRenderer r = new MyRenderer(8);
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, new NumberAxis("X"), new NumberAxis("Y"), r);
JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(plot);
…
private static class MyRenderer extends XYLineAndShapeRenderer {

    private final int anchor;

    public MyRenderer(int acnchor) {
        this.anchor = acnchor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawPrimaryLine(XYItemRendererState state, Graphics2D g2,
        XYPlot plot, XYDataset dataset, int pass, int series, int item,
        ValueAxis domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis, Rectangle2D dataArea) {
        if (item == anchor) {
            return;
        }
        …
        double x0 = dataset.getXValue(series, anchor);
        double y0 = dataset.getYValue(series, anchor);
        …
    }
}
```