# JfreeChart LineAndShapeRenderer, How to setOutlinePaint for Line?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I've got a problem with setting an OutlinePaint to a line from LineAndShapeRenderer in JFreeChart.

I've found this article http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=28347&p=78648&hilit=outlines+2d+line#p78648 which describes my problem also.

David.Gilbert writes "You'll have to modify the LineAndShapeRenderer code, because right now it just draws a single line between the data points (using the seriesPaint)." This was in 2009 and I can't find any todays solutions.

Does anybody has an idea how to modify the LineAndShapeRenderer to set the Outline of the line.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to override the [`drawItem()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html#drawItem-java.awt.Graphics2D-org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRendererState-java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D-org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot-org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis-org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis-org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset-int-int-int-) method of [`LineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html). In your implementation, you'll need to recapitulate the existing code, using the public accessors, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29243713/230513) for `XYLineAndShapeRenderer`. The existing [implementation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/LineAndShapeRenderer.html#line.887) uses the graphics context's `fill()` method to render a shape and `draw()` to stoke its outline; each invocation can have a different paint setting. No similar dichotomy exists for `draw(line)`, but you can get a comparable effect using a composite `Stroke`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343420/230513).

> I don't know how to set each paint.

Starting form this example, `draw()` a `Line2D` with one color and the default `Stroke`:

```
Line2D shape = new Line2D.Double(PAD, PAD, SIZE - PAD, SIZE - PAD);
g.setColor(Color.blue);
g.draw(shape);
```

And `draw()` the outline with another color and a `CompositeStroke`:

```
BasicStroke s1 = new BasicStroke(16f);
BasicStroke s2 = new BasicStroke(1f);
g.setStroke(new CompositeStroke(s1, s2));
g.setColor(Color.red);
g.draw(shape);
```

See also this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7343352/230513).

[image]

Comment: I choosed the way with the CompositeStroke, but I don't know how to set each paint.

Comment: @CrazyFisch: I've elaborated above.